# Does Cassandra startup times depend upon the number of commit log files?

Tags: cassandra, commit, cassandra-4.0

I have restarted my Cassandra without draining the node, now when Cassandra started it. It took more than 20-25 min to start accepting client connection.
As Cassandra was reading the commit log files.

So, does Cassandra startup time depend upon commit log files?

Note: Running a single node Cassandra v4.0.

Comment: So this question is more about ops than programming and should probably be moved to dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  If the node restarts without a “drain” operation, it will reconcile its data with the unprocessed commitlog files.  Any data which was not yet committed to disk will be written at startup time.

> Apart from reconciliation from unprocessed commitlog files, is there any other factor that leads to increase in Cassandra boot up time?

Well, there are several in-memory structures which need to be built at startup (like the index summary).  Additional things like the prepared statement cache get loaded as well.  Processing the commitlog can also trigger a compaction, which could also slow things down.

So sure, there are some additional things which happen, but the processing of the commitlog is the most time consuming.

> Would it be possible to figure out a total time will be taken by cassandra to bootup based on the size of commitlog files?

In theory, yes.  But it depends on a lot of different factors based on the size of the files, platform and abstraction of the underlying disk hardware.  I've seen it take 20 minutes for a node to start with 100 or so 8GB commitlog files.  But that might be different for you.  I'd `watch` the commitlog dir in another terminal/ssh session while it starts to get a feel for the time:

```
watch -n5 "ls data/commitlog/ | wc -l"
```

Comment: Apart from reconciliation from unprocessed commitlog files, is there any other factor that leads to increase in Cassandra boot up time?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to figure out a total time will be taken by cassandra to bootup based on the size of commitlog files?

Comment: @AmanJain edit made.